# FILE* as a public

Tags: c++, c

Once again I seek support here.

For example I have this fopen thing called fp

```
FILE * fp;

fp=fopen("Entity.dat","wb");
```

And I have x functions and there is need to use this thing in all of them, so the question is how can I make it public/global scope.

Comment: Don't. Pass it as a parameter, ideally after validating it as non-NULL.

Comment: Just because we smoke the same thing... If you cannot pass the file descriptor to the functions, you should be able to declare it in the header.

But I don't see how just putting it outside of `main()` fails to do the trick.

Comment: Why is this tagged `c++` if you are clearly working in `c` only?

Comment: Declare it outside the function scope in case of "C". But, I don't understand why can't you pass it as input to your x functions.

Comment: Than bundle related operations and data in a class or a namespace. Besides, it seems like the variable only needs to be visible in a single or limited scope.

Comment: @undefined `Once again I seek support here.`.Well, 'Once again you get support here`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `extern`:

the_file.h

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

...

extern FILE *file;

#endif
```

the_file.cpp

```
#include "file.h"

FILE *file;
```

Then open the file and store the handle in `file`. Next, you can use `file` where do you need.

Comment: Open the file and assign the handle to `file' inside main() or any other function?Can u clarify a little?

Comment: It depends on the programer to decide, for example he can open it first in then main.

Answer (score 7):

Ideally, you should simply pass it as a parameter to whatever functions need to use it:

```
void func( FILE *f, ... )
{
  // do something with f
}

int main( void )
{
  FILE *fp = fopen( "Entity.dat", "wb" );
  ...
  func( fp, ... );
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have a choice, please pass it as a parameter, if you really really don't have any choice, then you could consider about singleton.

c++11

```
template<typename T>
class meyersSingleton
{
public:
  static T& instance()
  {
    static T theSingleton;
    return theSingleton;
  }

  meyersSingleton() = delete;
  ~meyersSingleton() = delete;
  meyersSingleton(meyersSingleton const&) = delete;
  meyersSingleton& operator=(meyersSingleton const&) = delete;

};
```

c++98

```
template<typename T>
class meyersSingleton
{
public:
  static T& instance()
  {
    static T theSingleton;
    return theSingleton;
  }

private :
  meyersSingleton();
  ~meyersSingleton();
  meyersSingleton(meyersSingleton const&);
  meyersSingleton& operator=(meyersSingleton const&);

};
```

you could use it as this way

```
#include <cstdio>

template<typename T>
class meyersSingleton
{
public:
  static T& instance()
  {
    static T theSingleton;
    return theSingleton;
  }

  meyersSingleton() = delete;
  ~meyersSingleton() = delete;
  meyersSingleton(meyersSingleton const&) = delete;
  meyersSingleton& operator=(meyersSingleton const&) = delete;

};

void read_file()
{
    char buffer [100];
    fgets (buffer , 100 , meyersSingleton<FILE*>::instance());
    printf("%s", buffer);    
}

int main()
{             
    FILE **a = &meyersSingleton<FILE*>::instance();
    *a = fopen("coeff", "rb");

    read_file();   

    return 0;
}
```

not a very intuitive solution, but it will guarantee you only have a global and single FILE.

If you need more single FILE, you could add one more template parameter

```
template<typename T, size_t N = 0>
class meyersSingleton
{
public:
  static T& instance()
  {
    static T theSingleton;
    return theSingleton;
  }

  meyersSingleton() = delete;
  ~meyersSingleton() = delete;
  meyersSingleton(meyersSingleton const&) = delete;
  meyersSingleton& operator=(meyersSingleton const&) = delete;

};
```

If you are using c, then just omit this solution.

Edit : In most of the cases, singleton considered as a bad solution,  an anti-pattern which
should no be used and leave it alone.Here are some good articles discussing about the pros and cons of singleton.

[why singleton is so bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)
[Singleton I love you, but you're bringing me down](http://www.codingwithoutcomments.com/)

Don't take me wrong, singleton do solve one problem--it guarantee you will only have one
object(variable, resource, whatever) at a time, sometimes this is very useful(although it
is rare).Log is an example, we need log everywhere, and the log wouldn't write something into our program.

Comment: I get it's not the best answer, but what's with the down votes? What happened to preferring commenting and editing over down voting?

Comment: But seriously, @SteroMatching, you have to explain how using a singleton solves the OP's problem, instead of just saying how to implement a singleton.

Comment: -1: Singletons are rarely needed, often abused, and in this case they add complexity for no benefit. I don't believe it is a good idea to point a beginner towards inappropriate solutions. The only suggestion I can make to improve the answer is to remove it (an alternative would be to extend it to explain why a singleton isn't a good choice here, but that would be well outside the scope of the original question).